# What styling is used for the hover state of a Close Button on a Bootstrap Dismissible Alert?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, less, frontend

When I hover over the close button on a [Bootstrap 3 Dismissible Alert](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissible), what styling am I seeing?

I know the colour is changed to black, but I can't figure out what the opacity is.

Context: I'm working backwards and putting this into Sketch for a design using customised Bootstrap components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the inspect elements in chrome browser you can toggle hover effects, you see the `button` having the `.close` class. This is what causing the button to be black. Following styles apply:

```
.close:focus, .close:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I couldn't spot how to view that in the inspector. Forcing a hover state was what I was after

Answer (score 0):

You're actually seeing the `.close:hover` style there